# Adding Vector Assets to an Android Studio Project doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got the following problem: I try to add a vector asset to my Android-Project. I've followed the steps described [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html). But when I choose my local SVG file I cannot import the file. I receive the following exception: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10`.

I've created the vector-image with Illustrator and saved it as a SVG 1.1-File.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by myself. The issue is known and addressed [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198808). To solve the Problem just install Preview 2.0 of Android Studio.

I hope this might help.